# Rails 5: request.cookies and cookies are both nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

We are using Rails 5.1.4

Our controller has this method:

```
  def home
      if cookies[:_ga].blank?
          random_id = (0...9).map { ('0'..'9').to_a[rand(10)] }.join
          timestamp = (Time.new().to_i*1000).to_s
          cookies[:_ga] = {
              value: '1.2.' + random_id + '.' + timestamp,
              expires: 2.year.from_now,
              domain: 'proxyamp-thiagolcmelo.c9users.io'
          }
      end
  end
```

The cookie's value is something like **1.2.922688780.1514590140000**, it is being set in the browser properly:

[image]

Once it is stored in the browser, (in another request) I can see it been sent again in the Chrome's Network window:

[image]

But in the controller:

- `request.cookies`
- `cookies`

are both nil.

How can I get the cookie's value again?

## Edit 1.0

The problem is that the `cookies` is empty when the controller action is called. The controller is filling the cookie properly, but it is not being able of finding the cookie in the **request**.

Comment: Hi Thiago, I couldn't reproduce this error that you are having... I've just started a new app with rails 5.1.4, added a cookie on home request and the cookie is present on another request... Can you send more information? #sextou

Comment: Hi Maximillian, thank you very much for taking this time and giving it a try. 
I wonder whether I am just too tired... that's weird, actually, insane. Would you mind in place your code as answer?  #sextou :D